# Combinatorial Equality

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to understand the following equality:

$$(1+x)^n(x+1)^n=\left(\sum_{a=0}^n\binom{n}{a}x^a\right)\left(\sum_{b=0}^n\binom{n}{b}x^{n-b}\right)=\sum_{c=0}^{2n}\left(\sum_{a+n-b=c}\binom{n}{a}\binom{n}{b}\right)x^c$$

I understand the first equality (it's just a n application of Newton's formula) but I'm having trouble understanding why:

$$\left(\sum_{a=0}^n\binom{n}{a}x^a\right)\left(\sum_{b=0}^n\binom{n}{b}x^{n-b}\right)=\sum_{c=0}^{2n}\left(\sum_{a+n-b=c}\binom{n}{a}\binom{n}{b}\right)x^c$$

I think a combinatorial proof would be more helpful than an analytical one

Comment: It's not an actual combinatorial relationship (at least not sensibly).  It should be found using $\sum a_n\sum b_k=\sum\sum a_nb_k$ (when two things multiply, distribute the terms) and then a strange manipulation (rearrange so $x^c$ is in the order $c=0,1,2,3,\dots$) of the sum indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It’s just ordinary polynomial multiplication. Each of the factors is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$, so the product is a polynomial of degree $2n$. Suppose that $0\le c\le 2n$, and we want to find the coefficient of $x^c$ in the product

$$\left(\sum_{a=0}^n\binom{n}ax^a\right)\left(\sum_{b=0}^n\binom{n}bx^{n-b}\right)\;.$$

Before we collect terms, each term of this product has the form

$$\binom{n}a\binom{n}bx^{a+n-b}$$

for some $a,b\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$; we want the ones such that

$$\binom{n}a\binom{n}bx^{a+n-b}=\binom{n}a\binom{n}bx^c\;,$$

which means that we want the ones for which $a+n-b=c$. When we collect those terms into a single $x^c$ term, the combined coefficient is the sum of all of the individual coefficients $\binom{n}a\binom{n}b$ for which $a+n-b=c$, and that’s exactly what

$$\sum_{a+n-b=c}\binom{n}a\binom{n}b\tag{1}$$

gives us.

It may be a little easier to see if we rewrite $a+n-b=c$ as $n=a+n-c$. That makes it a little easier to see that the $x^c$ terms in the product are

$$\binom{n}0\binom{n}{n-c}x^c+\binom{n}1\binom{n}{1+n-c}x^c+\ldots+\binom{n}c\binom{n}{c+n-c}x^c\;,$$

or

$$\sum_{a=0}^n\binom{n}a\binom{n}{a+n-c}x^c\;,\tag{2}$$

so that

$$(1+x)^n(x+1)^n=\sum_{c=0}^{2n}\left(\sum_{a=0}^c\binom{n}a\binom{n}{a+n-c}\right)x^c\;.$$

Though they look different, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same sum.